# Sequence of coordinates

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I have binary file that contains information about pieces of land. Each piece of the has:

1. height
2. type - 0 for grass, 1 for desert, 2 for water 3 for road, 4 for buildings
3. attendance

I have to create function that reads the binary file and fill a linked list.

Then I have to create road by sequence of coordinates entered by the user until -1 is entered. Road cannot be built on water or buildings.This is what I have been struggling for 2 days.

This is my code.
I guess it won't work that way but I can't think of anything else

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Map
{
   int height;
   int type;
   int att;
   struct Map *next;
}Map;

Map* read(void)
{
    FILE* file;
    int i;
    char fName[50];
    printf("Enter the map's name (.bin): ");
    scanf("%s",fName);

    Map *head=NULL;
    Map *curr=NULL;
    Map  cell;

    if((file = fopen(fName, "rb"))==NULL) exit(1);

    fread(&size_x, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    fread(&size_y, sizeof(int), 1, file);

    printf("size x: %d\n",size_x);
    printf("size y: %d\n",size_y);

    for(i = 0; i < size_x*size_y; ++i)
    {
        Map *temp;
        temp=malloc(sizeof(Map));
        if(head==NULL)
        {
            head=temp;
            curr=temp;
        }
        curr->next=temp;
        curr=temp;
        fread(&cell,sizeof(Map),1,file);
        temp->height=cell.height;
        temp->type=cell.type;
        temp->att=cell.att;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return head;
}
void BuildRoad(Map* root)
    {   
        //size_x and size_y read from the file
        int matrix[size_x][size_y];   
        int i,j;

        Map* curr_item = root;
        while(curr_item!=NULL || (x!=-1 || y!=-1))
        {
            scanf("%d", &x);
            scanf("%d", &y);
            for(i=0;i<size_x; i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<size_y; j++)
                {
                    if((i==x && j==y) && (curr_item->type!=2 && curr_item->type!=4))
                        printf("[%d]", curr_item->type);
                    else if(curr_item->type==2 && curr_item->type==4)
                        printf("You can't build road on water or buildings\n");
                    else printf("[ ]");
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
         curr_item=curr_item->next;
        }
    }
int main()
{
    Map *root=NULL;
    root=read();
    BuildRoad(root);
}
```

This is what I get 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V7QD.jpg

```
Enter the map's name (.bin): 1
size x: 2
size y: 2
0 1
[ ][ ]
[ ][ ]
1 0
[ ][ ]
[1][ ]
1 1
[ ][ ]
[ ][ ]
0 0
[ ][ ]
[ ][ ]
1 1

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 18.746 s
```

I want it to be that way:

```
[1][3][2]  
[0][1][1]
```

But I have no idea how it will be done.

Comment: Copy & paste the output from your program into the question rather than posting an image.

Comment: Why did you enter `2` and `2` for map Width and Height if you want a 3x2 size?

Comment: The size is contained in the file. I do not care what the size is, just for the outup. For example if the size is 2x2 then 
[1][0]  
\n
[3][1] 

where the numbers are the type of the land

Comment: None of the relevant information is available to those who you are asking for help.  There's none of the code responsible for input; there's no dump of data in the `Map` structure that's passed in; there's not even a definition of the `Map` structure.  There's simply not enough information here for anyone to be able to help you meaningfully.  (And in future, use copy'n'paste rather than image files, please.)